# Undefined reference when trying to use Box2D's b2Body::SetUserData(void*)

Tags: c++, linker, box2d, undefined-reference

Here's some simple code to reproduce the problem:

```
#include <box2d/box2d.h>

int main()
{
    b2World world(b2Vec2_zero);
    b2BodyDef bdef;
    b2Body* body = world.CreateBody(&bdef);
    body->SetUserData(body);
    return 0;
}
```

That should compile according to everything I've read, and (for the pedants) I guess it technically does *compile*, but when I try (using `g++ test.cpp -lbox2d`) I get a linker error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccgHfvqv.o: in function `main':
test.cpp:(.text+0x75): undefined reference to `b2Body::SetUserData(void*)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I tried doing a Google search for `"undefined reference to b2Body::SetUserData(void*)"` but there were no results found.

I also tried setting it via the `b2BodyDef` instead, but the `userData` member in that struct seems to work differently, pointing to a `b2BodyUserData` struct with a single `pointer` member, which doesn't seem to be designed to hold the user data pointer, as setting an address there causes Box2D to write to that address later, corrupting the data. (I used a GDB watchpoint to check this.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out `SetUserData` was recently removed in Box2D 2.4.1. I've also noticed some of my old code that used the `b2BodyDef` method (I had forgotten I used that in the past) would no longer compile; previously it was just a direct `void*` pointer without the issue I mentioned.

Instead of doing `foo->SetUserData(bar)`, now it seems the correct way is `foo->GetUserData().pointer = bar`. ([Source](https://github.com/erincatto/box2d/pull/658))